# Joomla / Virtuemart - How to display level 2 subcategories on virtuemart homepage?

Tags: joomla, categories, virtuemart

I have a Joomla shop that stocks parts for cars.
I am using the Virtuemart component to handle the shop aspect.

The top parent categories for my products are;
Air filters
Oil filters
Fuel filters
Pollen filters

This means that the virtuemart side menu displays these 4 options, which is fine.
However, for the shop (virtuemart) homepage I want to display all the level 2 subcategories;
Audi
BMW
etc

I can't seem to find a ay to do this. Currently I'm stuck with just the 4 top parent categories being displayed on the homepage, when really I want the car manufacturers displayed there.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1) Simple answer:  you can try this hack, which displays all subcategories:

in administrator/components/com_virtuemart/classes/ps_product_category.php, look for the line

```
$allowed = false;
if( $depth_list[$n] > 0 ) 
{
```

change it to

```
$allowed = true;   //show all by default
if( $depth_list[$n] > 0 ) 
{
```

2) I think the real issue here is more your organizational/classification system... it's probably not optimal to be using categories/sub-categories to represent brands/makes as well as types-of-products.

I'd suggest you look more into [Virtumart documentation](http://virtuemart.net/home/manuals) and read up on "Product Types" as well as "Product Attributes" --  I think these would be more suited for what you're trying to do  (as I believe you can filter cross-category product-search-results by product-types)

hope this helps,
E

Answer (score 0):

Virtuemart 2.0 now displays 2 levels which will fit your need. To go 3 levels deep you can use a workaround until a third party module comes.

The workaround is here: http://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?topic=96816.msg321564#msg321564

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) for you to edit the answer to include the essential parts of the solution, and provide the link for reference.